# asyncio.gather vs asyncio.wait (vs asyncio.TaskGroup)

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

[`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) and [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) seem to have similar uses: I have a bunch of async things that I want to execute/wait for (not necessarily waiting for one to finish before the next one starts).

Since Python 3.11 there is yet another similar feature, [`asyncio.TaskGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.TaskGroup).

They use a different syntax, and differ in some details, but it seems very un-pythonic to me to have several functions that have such a huge overlap in functionality.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Although similar in general cases ("run and get results for many tasks"), each function has some specific functionality for other cases (and see also `TaskGroup` for Python 3.11+ below):

## [`asyncio.gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)

Returns a Future instance, allowing high level grouping of tasks:

```
import asyncio
from pprint import pprint

import random


async def coro(tag):
    print(">", tag)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))
    print("<", tag)
    return tag


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

group1 = asyncio.gather(*[coro("group 1.{}".format(i)) for i in range(1, 6)])
group2 = asyncio.gather(*[coro("group 2.{}".format(i)) for i in range(1, 4)])
group3 = asyncio.gather(*[coro("group 3.{}".format(i)) for i in range(1, 10)])

all_groups = asyncio.gather(group1, group2, group3)

results = loop.run_until_complete(all_groups)

loop.close()

pprint(results)
```

All tasks in a group can be cancelled by calling `group2.cancel()` or even `all_groups.cancel()`.  See also `.gather(..., return_exceptions=True)`,

## [`asyncio.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait)

Supports waiting to be stopped after the first task is done, or after a specified timeout, allowing lower level precision of operations:

```
import asyncio
import random


async def coro(tag):
    print(">", tag)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 5))
    print("<", tag)
    return tag


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = [coro(i) for i in range(1, 11)]

print("Get first result:")
finished, unfinished = loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED))

for task in finished:
    print(task.result())
print("unfinished:", len(unfinished))

print("Get more results in 2 seconds:")
finished2, unfinished2 = loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.wait(unfinished, timeout=2))

for task in finished2:
    print(task.result())
print("unfinished2:", len(unfinished2))

print("Get all other results:")
finished3, unfinished3 = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(unfinished2))

for task in finished3:
    print(task.result())

loop.close()
```

---

## [`TaskGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups) (Python 3.11+)

**Update**: Python 3.11 introduces [`TaskGroup`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups) which can "automatically" await more than one task without `gather()` or `await()`:

```
# Python 3.11+ ONLY!
async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        task1 = tg.create_task(some_coro(...))
        task2 = tg.create_task(another_coro(...))
    print("Both tasks have completed now.")
```

Comment: "The single asterisk form ( *args ) is used to pass a non-keyworded, variable-length argument list, and the double asterisk form is used to pass a keyworded, variable-length argument list"

Comment: In the `asyncio.gather()` code, If the code that creates those three groups is contained within a function body, you can get rid of the `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` and refactor the code adding an `await` to the `asyncio.gather(group1, group2, group3)` making it slightly simpler, and all the lines related with the loop variables will no longer be needed

Comment: Dear Udi, in your *asyncio.gather* example, whenever I run in my computer, I get the "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running", even though the results are properly evaluated. How can one solve this RuntimeError? Shouldn't we use the loop object?

Comment: @PhilipeRiskallaLeal: copy the text into a `demo.py` file and execute it from the command line using `python demo.py`

Comment: `run_until_complete` causes issues when there already is an async loop running. What alternative is there to await for the tasks to finish **synchronously**?

Comment: i get "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running" when copying the asyncio.wait example (but not the asyncio.gather example) into a file and running with `python demo.py`. this is with python3.11.2

Answer (score 94):

A very important distinction, which is easy to miss, is the default behavior of these two functions, when it comes to exceptions.

---

I'll use this example to simulate a coroutine that will raise exceptions, sometimes -

```
import asyncio
import random


async def a_flaky_tsk(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(i)  # bit of fuzz to simulate a real-world example

    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i, "ok")
    else:
        print(i, "crashed!")
        raise ValueError

coros = [a_flaky_tsk(i) for i in range(10)]
```

---

`await asyncio.gather(*coros)` outputs -

```
0 ok
1 crashed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py", line 20, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Users/dev/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Users/dev/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py", line 17, in main
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)
  File "/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py", line 12, in a_flaky_tsk
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

As you can see, the coros after index `1` never got to execute. Future returned by `gather()` is done at that point (unlike `wait()`) and program terminates, but if you could keep the program alive, other coroutines still would have chance to run:

```
async def main():
    coros = [a_flaky_tsk(i) for i in range(10)]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()

# 0 ok
# 1 crashed!
# Task exception was never retrieved
#  ....
# 2 ok
# 3 crashed!
# 4 ok
# 5 crashed!
# 6 ok
# 7 crashed!
# 8 ok
# 9 crashed!
```

---

But `await asyncio.wait(coros)` continues to execute tasks, even if some of them fail (Future returned by `wait()` is not done, unlike `gather()`) -

```
0 ok
1 crashed!
2 ok
3 crashed!
4 ok
5 crashed!
6 ok
7 crashed!
8 ok
9 crashed!
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-10' coro=<a_flaky_tsk() done, defined at /Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py:6> exception=ValueError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py", line 12, in a_flaky_tsk
    raise ValueError
ValueError
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-8' coro=<a_flaky_tsk() done, defined at /Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py:6> exception=ValueError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py", line 12, in a_flaky_tsk
    raise ValueError
ValueError
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<a_flaky_tsk() done, defined at /Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py:6> exception=ValueError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py", line 12, in a_flaky_tsk
    raise ValueError
ValueError
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<a_flaky_tsk() done, defined at /Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py:6> exception=ValueError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py", line 12, in a_flaky_tsk
    raise ValueError
ValueError
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<a_flaky_tsk() done, defined at /Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py:6> exception=ValueError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/xxx.py", line 12, in a_flaky_tsk
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

---

Of course, this behavior can be changed for both by using -

`asyncio.gather(..., return_exceptions=True)`

or,

`asyncio.wait([...], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)`

---

But it doesn't end here!

Notice:
`Task exception was never retrieved`
in the logs above.

`asyncio.wait()` won't re-raise exceptions from the child tasks until you `await` them individually. (The stacktrace in the logs are just messages, they cannot be caught!)

```
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(coros)
for tsk in done:
    try:
        await tsk
    except Exception as e:
        print("I caught:", repr(e))
```

Output -

```
0 ok
1 crashed!
2 ok
3 crashed!
4 ok
5 crashed!
6 ok
7 crashed!
8 ok
9 crashed!
I caught: ValueError()
I caught: ValueError()
I caught: ValueError()
I caught: ValueError()
I caught: ValueError()
```

---

On the other hand, to catch exceptions with `asyncio.gather()`, you must -

```
results = await asyncio.gather(*coros, return_exceptions=True)
for result_or_exc in results:
    if isinstance(result_or_exc, Exception):
        print("I caught:", repr(result_or_exc))
```

(Same output as before)

Comment: I never understood `Task exception was never retrieved` error until I came across this post. Thanks a lot for great explanation..

Comment: @SauravKumar me too! Heck, this is so helpful!!

Comment: To help someone to understand. `Task exception was never retrieved` is shown where there are no references left to the task object (right before destroying). Python notifies you about exception in the task because you will never be able to gain acces to it later.

Answer (score 81):

`asyncio.wait` is more low level than `asyncio.gather`.

As the name suggests, `asyncio.gather` mainly focuses on gathering the results. It waits on a bunch of futures and returns their results in a given order.

`asyncio.wait` just waits on the futures. And instead of giving you the results directly, it gives done and pending tasks. You have to manually collect the values.

Moreover, you could specify to wait for all futures to finish or just the first one with `wait`.

Comment: @Kingname ..wat

Comment: do you mean that asyncio.gather will have to wait for all of them to complete,
while asyncio.wait will return to you the current status of each one (pending or not)?
Reading your answer is not clear to me

Comment: @EigenFool As of Python 3.9, `asyncio.wait` has a parameter called `return_when`, which you can use to control when the event loop should yield back to you. `asyncio.gather` does not have such parameter, the event loop only get back to you when all tasks have finished/failed. Read the official docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait

Comment: @ospider The parameter called `return_when` for `asyncio.wait` is already available in Python 3.5.9!
See here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait

Comment: @Kingname `python -m timeit "print('hello')"` gives 36.6 usec per loop, so 10000000000000 `print('hello')` will take 11.6 years to complete for just `print()` function

Answer (score 23):

I also noticed that you can provide a group of coroutines in wait() by simply specifying the list:

```
result=loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([
        say('first hello', 2),
        say('second hello', 1),
        say('third hello', 4)
    ]))
```

Whereas grouping in gather() is done by just specifying multiple coroutines:

```
result=loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
        say('first hello', 2),
        say('second hello', 1),
        say('third hello', 4)
    ))
```

Comment: Lists can also be used with `gather()`, e.g.: `asyncio.gather(*task_list)`

Comment: So can generators

Comment: How can you use this gather without blocking the rest of the script?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the dramatically easier to read example.

Comment: @thebeancounter You don't need to `await` right-away!
`group = asyncio.gather(*aws)` **returns an awaitable/future for the group directly**, which represents all the combined tasks.
The tasks can run soon after the `asyncio.gather`-call, e.g. when there is an `await` for something else (like `asyncio.sleep`) or when accessing the future (like `group.done()`).
You only need to use `await group`, when you want to make sure the tasks are done or cancelled and to collect all the results.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to all the previous answers, I would like to tell about the different behavior of `gather()` and `wait()` in case they are **cancelled**.

#### [Gather()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) cancellation

If `gather()` is cancelled, **all submitted awaitables (that have not completed yet) are also cancelled**.

#### [Wait()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) cancellation

If the `wait()`ing task is cancelled, it simply throws an `CancelledError` and the waited tasks remain intact.

Simple example:

```
import asyncio


async def task(arg):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return arg


async def cancel_waiting_task(work_task, waiting_task):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    waiting_task.cancel()
    try:
        await waiting_task
        print("Waiting done")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Waiting task cancelled")

    try:
        res = await work_task
        print(f"Work result: {res}")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Work task cancelled")


async def main():
    work_task = asyncio.create_task(task("done"))
    waiting = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.wait({work_task}))
    await cancel_waiting_task(work_task, waiting)

    work_task = asyncio.create_task(task("done"))
    waiting = asyncio.gather(work_task)
    await cancel_waiting_task(work_task, waiting)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
asyncio.wait()
Waiting task cancelled
Work result: done
----------------
asyncio.gather()
Waiting task cancelled
Work task cancelled
```

---

#### Application example

Sometimes it becomes necessary to combine `wait()` and `gather()` functionality. For example, we want to wait for the completion of *at least one* task and *cancel* the rest pending tasks after that, and if the `waiting` itself was *canceled*, then *also cancel all pending* tasks.

As real examples, let's say we have a disconnect event and a work task. And we want to wait for the results of the work task, but if the connection was lost, then cancel it. Or we will make several parallel requests, but upon completion of at least one response, cancel all others.

It could be done this way:

```
import asyncio
from typing import Optional, Tuple, Set


async def wait_any(
        tasks: Set[asyncio.Future], *, timeout: Optional[int] = None,
) -> Tuple[Set[asyncio.Future], Set[asyncio.Future]]:
    tasks_to_cancel: Set[asyncio.Future] = set()
    try:
        done, tasks_to_cancel = await asyncio.wait(
            tasks, timeout=timeout, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
        )
        return done, tasks_to_cancel
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        tasks_to_cancel = tasks
        raise
    finally:
        for task in tasks_to_cancel:
            task.cancel()


async def task():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)


async def cancel_waiting_task(work_task, waiting_task):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    waiting_task.cancel()
    try:
        await waiting_task
        print("Waiting done")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Waiting task cancelled")

    try:
        res = await work_task
        print(f"Work result: {res}")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Work task cancelled")


async def check_tasks(waiting_task, working_task, waiting_conn_lost_task):
    try:
        await waiting_task
        print("waiting is done")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("waiting is cancelled")

    try:
        await waiting_conn_lost_task
        print("connection is lost")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("waiting connection lost is cancelled")

    try:
        await working_task
        print("work is done")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("work is cancelled")


async def work_done_case():
    working_task = asyncio.create_task(task())
    connection_lost_event = asyncio.Event()
    waiting_conn_lost_task = asyncio.create_task(connection_lost_event.wait())
    waiting_task = asyncio.create_task(wait_any({working_task, waiting_conn_lost_task}))
    await check_tasks(waiting_task, working_task, waiting_conn_lost_task)


async def conn_lost_case():
    working_task = asyncio.create_task(task())
    connection_lost_event = asyncio.Event()
    waiting_conn_lost_task = asyncio.create_task(connection_lost_event.wait())
    waiting_task = asyncio.create_task(wait_any({working_task, waiting_conn_lost_task}))
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    connection_lost_event.set()  # <---
    await check_tasks(waiting_task, working_task, waiting_conn_lost_task)


async def cancel_waiting_case():
    working_task = asyncio.create_task(task())
    connection_lost_event = asyncio.Event()
    waiting_conn_lost_task = asyncio.create_task(connection_lost_event.wait())
    waiting_task = asyncio.create_task(wait_any({working_task, waiting_conn_lost_task}))
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    waiting_task.cancel()  # <---
    await check_tasks(waiting_task, working_task, waiting_conn_lost_task)


async def main():
    print("Work done")
    print("-------------------")
    await work_done_case()
    print("\nConnection lost")
    print("-------------------")
    await conn_lost_case()
    print("\nCancel waiting")
    print("-------------------")
    await cancel_waiting_case()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
Work done
-------------------
waiting is done
waiting connection lost is cancelled
work is done

Connection lost
-------------------
waiting is done
connection is lost
work is cancelled

Cancel waiting
-------------------
waiting is cancelled
waiting connection lost is cancelled
work is cancelled
```