# Python parallel asynchronous processing of api calls from iterable

Tags: python, asynchronous, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm creating an automation script for Google Workspace where it fetches an direct children of some organization unit and then fetches children of all these OUs at the same time. While searching the web for the answer whether multiprocessing, threading or asynchronous processing will work best for me I understood that asyncio is going to help me with this issue. I have created a class `Google Tenant` which holds the connection to google api and the fetched users.
However, my problem right now is that the script still is not asynchronous but it works in sequence rather than making the calls asynchronously

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

import logging
import asyncio

class GoogleTenant:
    def __init__(self, api: str, version: str):
        config: ScriptConfig = ScriptConfig()
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(config["gcloud"]["keypath"],
                                                                            scopes=SCOPES)
        delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(config["gcloud"]["subject"])
        self.service = build(api, version, credentials=delegated_credentials)
        self.users_list = []

    def fetch_users(self):
        users_ous = self.service.orgunits().list(customerId="my_customer", orgUnitPath="/example", type="children", fields="organizationUnits/orgUnitPath").execute()
        ous_list = [ou["orgUnitPath"] for ou in users_ous["organizationUnits"]]
        asyncio.run(self._crawl_ous(ous_list))

    async def _crawl_ous(self, ous: list):
        crawling_result = await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.create_task(self._fetch_users_from_ou(ou)) for ou in ous])
        for result in crawling_result:
            logging.info(f"Crawling result of ou {result[0]["organizations"][0]["department"]}: {len(result)}")
            self.users_list.extend(result)

    async def _fetch_users_from_ou(self, ou):
        call_parameters = {
            "customer": "my_customer",
            "maxResults": 500,
            "projection": "basic",
            "query": f"orgUnitPath='{str(ou)}'",
            "fields": "users/id,users/name,users/primaryEmail,users/suspended,users/emails,users/organizations/primary,users/organizations/department,users/recoveryEmail,nextPageToken"
        }
        logger.debug(f"Fetching users from {ou}")
        users_from_ou = self.service.users().list(**call_parameters).execute()
        user_fetching_result: list = users_from_ou["users"]
        logger.debug(f"Initial fetch from {ou}: {len(users_from_ou["users"])}")
        if "nextPageToken" in users_from_ou:
            next_page_token = users_from_ou["nextPageToken"]
        else:
            return user_fetching_result
        while True:
            users_from_ou = self.service.users().list(**call_parameters, pageToken=next_page_token).execute()
            logger.debug(f"Next fetch from {ou}: {len(users_from_ou["users"])}")
            user_fetching_result.extend(users_from_ou["users"])
            if "nextPageToken" in users_from_ou:
                next_page_token = users_from_ou["nextPageToken"]
            else:
                return user_fetching_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    google_tenant = GoogleTenant("admin", "directory_v1")
    google_tenant.fetch_users()
```

The execution result of the following:

```
DEBUG:root:Fetching users from /example/child1
DEBUG:root:Initial fetch from /example/child1: 500
DEBUG:root:Next fetch from /example/child1: 500
DEBUG:root:Next fetch from /example/child1: 500
DEBUG:root:Next fetch from /example/child1: 258
DEBUG:root:Fetching users from /example/child2
DEBUG:root:Initial fetch from /example/child2: 500
DEBUG:root:Next fetch from /example/child2: 500
DEBUG:root:Next fetch from /example/child2: 500
...
```

I've tried to enter the await statement in places however I seem to misunderstand how it should as per my understanding the await statement makes the function wait for the result before continuing function execution.
How can I make python execute these concurrently?

## Update 1

I reformatted parts of the code as per @Michael Butscher suggestion and also added my imports in the previous block

```
    def fetch_users(self):
        users_ous = self.service.orgunits().list(customerId="my_customer", orgUnitPath="/example", type="children", fields="organizationUnits/orgUnitPath").execute()
        ous_list = [ou["orgUnitPath"] for ou in users_ous["organizationUnits"]]
        logger.debug(f"Fetched and sanitized ous: {pprint.pformat(ous_list)}")
        asyncio.run(self._crawl_ous(ous_list))

    async def _crawl_ous(self, ous: list):
        tasks = [self._crawler_proxy(ou) for ou in ous]
        crawling_result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for result in crawling_result:
            logger.info(f"Crawling result: {len(result)}")
            self.users_list.extend(result)

    async  def _crawler_proxy(self, *args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        return await loop.run_in_executor(None, self._fetch_users_from_ou(*args, **kwargs))
```

Comment: It seems you use a library which does the actual API calls. If that library doesn't support asynchronous calls, you can only use [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)  (meaning multithreading or maybe multiprocessing) which seems not really better than using an executor directly without using asynchronous code in your case.

Comment: So if I understand correctly yo usuggest that I should give up `asyncio` and rather use `threading` to execute these function calls using multiple threads?

Comment: If your library doesn't provide async functions and you can't (or don't want to) find another library or do the API calls directly with an async function or library (e.g. requests variant `requests-async`) then yes.

Comment: Instead of using `threading` directly you may use an `Executor` from `concurrent.futures` or `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

Comment: I would like to use this library nonetheless as it is google's supported library `google-api-python-client` which I forgot to include in the post, for which I'm sorry. However based on your suggestion and as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263596/asyncio-collecting-results-from-an-async-function-in-an-executor) I modified my code yet I see no effect on the execution .

Comment: Post this as update of the question as properly formatted code. It is hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added the code block as update 1.

Comment: If `self._fetch_users_from_ou` is async yet, it wouldn't work at all (because `run_in_executor` expects a synchronous function) and if it is not, you must not call `self._fetch_users_from_ou` in the `run_in_executor` call because this executes `self._fetch_users_from_ou` in the main thread. Instead do `from functools import partial` and replace `return await loop.run_in_executor(None, self._fetch_users_from_ou(*args, **kwargs))` by `return await loop.run_in_executor(None, partial(self._fetch_users_from_ou, *args, **kwargs))`.

Comment: I tried the solution proposed however the program then finishes with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again thank you @Juris and @Michael Butscher for the provided suggestions and help. In the end I used different approach. The simplest solution in this case turned out to be `multiprocessing`. I used the `multiprocessing.Pool().map()` function. Below is the modified code.

```
    def fetch_users(self) -> None:
        config = ScriptConfig()
        users_ous = self.service.orgunits().list(customerId="my_customer", orgUnitPath="/example", type="children", fields="organizationUnits/orgUnitPath").execute()
        ous_list = [ou["orgUnitPath"] for ou in users_ous["organizationUnits"]]
        logger.debug(f"Fetched and sanitized ous: {pprint.pformat(ous_list)}")
        self._crawl_ous(ous_list)
        logger.info(f"Fetched users: {len(self.users_list)}")

    def _crawl_ous(self, ous: list[str]) -> None:
        users_list = []
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=30) as pool:
            crawling_results = pool.map(self._fetch_users_from_ou, ous)

        for result in crawling_results:
            logger.info(f"Crawling result: {len(result)}")
            self.users_list.extend(result)

    def _fetch_users_from_ou(self, ou):
        call_parameters = {
            "customer": "my_customer",
            "maxResults": 500,
            "projection": "basic",
            "query": f"orgUnitPath='{str(ou)}'",
            "fields": "users/id,users/name,users/primaryEmail,users/suspended,users/emails,users/organizations/primary,users/organizations/department,users/recoveryEmail,nextPageToken"
        }
        logger.info(f"Fetching users from {ou}")
        users_from_ou: dict = self.service.users().list(**call_parameters).execute()
        logger.debug(f"Initial fetch from {ou}: {len(users_from_ou["users"])}")
        user_fetching_result: list = users_from_ou["users"]
        if "nextPageToken" in users_from_ou:
            next_page_token: str = users_from_ou["nextPageToken"]
        else:
            return user_fetching_result
        while True:
            users_from_ou: dict = self.service.users().list(**call_parameters, pageToken=next_page_token).execute()
            logger.debug(f"Next fetch from {ou}: {len(users_from_ou["users"])}")
            user_fetching_result.extend(users_from_ou["users"])
            if "nextPageToken" in users_from_ou:
                next_page_token: str = users_from_ou["nextPageToken"]
            else:
                return user_fetching_result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main culprit is coroutine `_fetch_users_from_ou`. It does not have any `await` statement inside, so it means it will not allow any other task to run in between until this function executes, thus all of them run sequentially in `asyncio.gather` call inside your `_crawl_ous`.

You would want these changes:

`users_from_ou = await asyncio.to_thread( self.service.users().list(**call_parameters).execute)`

`users_from_ou = await asyncio.to_thread( self.service.users().list(**call_parameters, pageToken=next_page_token).execute)`

Assuming that you have python 3.9 or above and more about what this does: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads

Comment: So I implemented your suggestion and the effect was that all calls to `_fetch_users_from_ou` start at the same time however they fall into some kind of inifite loop as the first call `users_from_ou = await asyncio.to_thread( self.service.users().list(**call_parameters).execute)` doesn't move further wit the code

Comment: could be that `self.service.user().list(**call_paremeters).execute` is not thread safe. You can try to force it to only execute one call and see if it goes through. To try to go around the problem of `self.service.users()` not being thread safe, you can make it so that `self.service` is not used instead it is built on the fly in the function, something like:
```def make_call(*different_args):
service = build(api, version, credentials=delegated_credentials)
...do the calls you need return result...
```
But I am not sure here either.