# Wrapping asyncio.gather in a timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio

I've seen [asyncio.gather vs asyncio.wait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42231161/7954504), but am not sure if that addresses this particular question.  What I'm looking to do is wrap the `asyncio.gather()` coroutine in `asyncio.wait_for()`, with a `timeout` argument.  I also need to satisfy these conditions:

- `return_exceptions=True` (from `asyncio.gather()`) - rather than propagating exceptions to the task that awaits on `gather()`, I want to include exceptions instances in the results
- Order: retain the property of `asyncio.gather()` that the order of results is the same as the order of the input.  (Or otherwise, map the output back to the input.).  `asyncio.wait_for()` fails this criteria and I'm not sure of ideal way to achieve it.

The timeout is for the *entire* `asyncio.gather()` across the list of awaitables--if they get caught in the timeout or return an exception, either of those cases should just place an exception instance in the result list.

Consider this setup:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> import random
>>> from time import perf_counter
>>> from typing import Iterable
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
>>> async def coro(i, threshold=0.4):
...     await asyncio.sleep(i)
...     if i > threshold:
...         # For illustration's sake - some coroutines may raise,
...         # and we want to accomodate that and just test for exception
...         # instances in the results of asyncio.gather(return_exceptions=True)
...         raise Exception("i too high")
...     return i
... 
>>> async def main(n, it: Iterable):
...     res = await asyncio.gather(
...         *(coro(i) for i in it),
...         return_exceptions=True
...     )
...     return res
... 
>>> 
>>> random.seed(444)
>>> n = 10
>>> it = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
>>> start = perf_counter()
>>> res = asyncio.run(main(n, it=it))
>>> elapsed = perf_counter() - start
>>> print(f"Done main({n}) in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds")  # Expectation: ~1 seconds
Done main(10) in 0.86 seconds
>>> pprint(dict(zip(it, res)))
{0.01323751590501987: 0.01323751590501987,
 0.07422124156714727: 0.07422124156714727,
 0.3088946587429545: 0.3088946587429545,
 0.3113884366691503: 0.3113884366691503,
 0.4419557492849159: Exception('i too high'),
 0.4844375347808497: Exception('i too high'),
 0.5796792804615848: Exception('i too high'),
 0.6338658027451068: Exception('i too high'),
 0.7426396870165088: Exception('i too high'),
 0.8614799253779063: Exception('i too high')}
```

The program above, with `n = 10`, has an exected runtime of .5 seconds plus a bit of overhead when run asynchronously.  (`random.random()` will be uniformly distributed in [0, 1).)

Let's say I want to impose that as the timeout, on the entire operation (i.e. on the coroutine `main()`):

```
timeout = 0.5
```

Now, I can use `asyncio.wait()`, but the problem is that the results are `set` objects and so definitely can't guarantee the sorted return value property of `asyncio.gather()`:

```
>>> async def main(n, it, timeout) -> tuple:
...     tasks = [asyncio.create_task(coro(i)) for i in it]
...     done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=timeout)
...     return done, pending
... 
>>> timeout = 0.5
>>> random.seed(444)
>>> it = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
>>> start = perf_counter()
>>> done, pending = asyncio.run(main(n, it=it, timeout=timeout))
>>> for i in pending:
...     i.cancel()
>>> elapsed = perf_counter() - start
>>> print(f"Done main({n}) in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds")
Done main(10) in 0.50 seconds
>>> done
{<Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> exception=Exception('i too high')>, <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> exception=Exception('i too high')>, <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.3088946587429545>, <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.3113884366691503>, <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.01323751590501987>, <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.07422124156714727>}
>>> pprint(done)
{<Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> exception=Exception('i too high')>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.3113884366691503>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.07422124156714727>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> exception=Exception('i too high')>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.01323751590501987>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.3088946587429545>}
>>> pprint(pending)
{<Task cancelled coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1>>,
 <Task cancelled coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1>>,
 <Task cancelled coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1>>,
 <Task cancelled coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1>>}
```

As stated above, the issue is that I seemingly can't map back `task` instances to the inputs in `iterable`.  They task ids are effectively lost inside a function scope with `tasks = [asyncio.create_task(coro(i)) for i in it]`.  Is there a Pythonic way/use of asyncio API to mimic the behavior of `asyncio.gather()` here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking a look at the underlying [`_wait()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/742d768656512a469ce9571b1cbd777def7bc5ea/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L466) coroutine, this coroutine gets passed a list of tasks and will modify the state of those tasks in place.  This means that, within the scope of `main()`, the `tasks` from `tasks = [asyncio.create_task(coro(i)) for i in it]` will be modified by the call to `await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=timeout)`.  Instead of returning a `(done, pending)` tuple, one workaround is to just return `tasks` themselves, which retains order with the input `it`.  `wait()`/`_wait()` just separates the tasks into done/pending subsets and in this case we can discard those subsets and use the whole lists of `tasks` whose elements have been altered.

There are three possible tasks states in this case:

- A task returned a valid result (`coro()`) didn't raise an exception, and it finished under the `timeout`.  Its `.cancelled()` will be False, and it has a valid `.result()` that is not an exception instance
- A task got hit with the timeout before having a chance to return either a result or raise an exception.  It will show `.cancelled()` and its `.exception()` will raise a `CancelledError`
- A task that was allowed time to finished and raised an exception from `coro()`; it will show `.cancelled()` as False and its `exception()` will raise

(All of this is laid out in [asyncio/futures.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/futures.py).)

---

Illustration:

```
>>> # imports/other code snippets - see question
>>> async def main(n, it, timeout) -> tuple:
...     tasks = [asyncio.create_task(coro(i)) for i in it]
...     await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=timeout)
...     return tasks  # *not* (done, pending)

>>> timeout = 0.5
>>> random.seed(444)
>>> n = 10
>>> it = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
>>> start = perf_counter()
>>> tasks = asyncio.run(main(n, it=it, timeout=timeout))
>>> elapsed = perf_counter() - start
>>> print(f"Done main({n}) in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds")
Done main(10) in 0.50 seconds

>>> pprint(tasks)
[<Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.3088946587429545>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.01323751590501987>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> exception=Exception('i too high')>,
 <Task cancelled coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1>>,
 <Task cancelled coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1>>,
 <Task cancelled coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1>>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> exception=Exception('i too high')>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.3113884366691503>,
 <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1> result=0.07422124156714727>,
 <Task cancelled coro=<coro() done, defined at <stdin>:1>>]
```

Now to apply the logic from above, which lets `res` retain order corresponding to the inputs:

```
>>> res = []
>>> for t in tasks:
...     try:
...         r = t.result()
...     except Exception as e:
...         res.append(e)
...     else:
...         res.append(r)
>>> pprint(res)
[0.3088946587429545,
 0.01323751590501987,
 Exception('i too high'),
 CancelledError(),
 CancelledError(),
 CancelledError(),
 Exception('i too high'),
 0.3113884366691503,
 0.07422124156714727,
 CancelledError()]
>>> dict(zip(it, res))
{0.3088946587429545: 0.3088946587429545,
 0.01323751590501987: 0.01323751590501987,
 0.4844375347808497: Exception('i too high'),
 0.8614799253779063: concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError(),
 0.7426396870165088: concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError(),
 0.6338658027451068: concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError(),
 0.4419557492849159: Exception('i too high'),
 0.3113884366691503: 0.3113884366691503,
 0.07422124156714727: 0.07422124156714727,
 0.5796792804615848: concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError()}
```

Comment: From python 3.8 onwards `except Exception as e:` won't work. It should be changed to `except BaseException as e:` ... in the results code block.

Comment: @reservoirinvest can you share links to docs? I still succeed to do `except Exception as e:` in python 3.8