# How can I submit another task_list after one task_list finished in asyncio module?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm new to asyncio module， pls pardon me for my bad trial:

In my codes, I try to submit 100 tasks at first, then submit next 100 tasks after fore-100 tasks finished, then another next 100 tasks.

What should I do to make it work?

```py
# len(ad_accounts) = 1000 for example 
new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(new_loop)
task_list = [
            asyncio.ensure_future(_handle_account(account)) for ad_account in ad_accounts[:100]
        ]
#just submit 100 tasks here once
new_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task_list))
# then can I continuely submit next 100 tasks?
```

Comment: You are doing correctly, but should use `get_event_loop` instead of new and set. What's the problem you have?

Comment: @MatrixTai , thanks for replying, I just want to run part of 1000 tasks (100 for example) at once , and run next 100 tasks after fore 100 tasks finished..

Comment: @MatrixTai  Is this works ? `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task_list_100)) loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task_list_200)) loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task_list_300))...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to add,

1. `get_event_loop` will try to access any available event loop, if there is not, it will call `new_event_loop` with `set_event_loop`, [[Doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop).
2. Simply use `asyncio.gather` when you won't do any further actions individual task. Use `gather` provides you a way to stop whole task group as well, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231161/asyncio-gather-vs-asyncio-wait).
3. You may notice in the following, `()` generator is used instead of `[]` list comprehension, as you don't need the list actually be saved in memory, and you don't need it until iteration. Change back to `[]` bracket if it is not the case.

Whole working example will be:

```
# len(ad_accounts) = 1000 for example

chunk_size = 100
batched_tasks = (ad_accounts[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(ad_accounts), chunk_size))
_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

for task_group in batched_tasks:
    task_list = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(_handle_account(account)) for ad_account in task_group
    ]
    #just submit 100 tasks here once
    _loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*task_list))
    # Or _loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task_list))
```

Comment: thanks for your patience, benefit a lot from your words. :)