# Python websockets fails silently on `send`

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

In the minimal snippet bellow with both client producer/consumers and server, I force an error on the client's `send` method:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets


async def producer(websocket):
    for i in range(11):
        await websocket.send(i)  # Invalid type, fails silently
        # await websocket.send(str(i))  # Works


async def consumer(websocket):
    async for msg in websocket:
        i = int(msg)
        print(i)
        if i == 10:
            return


async def echo(websocket, path):
    try:
        async for msg in websocket:
            await websocket.send(msg)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
        print("Client disconnect.")


async def client():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
        consumer_task = consumer(websocket)
        producer_task = producer(websocket)
        await asyncio.wait([consumer_task, producer_task])


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8765))
loop.run_until_complete(client())
```

In the invalid type case, the code hangs indefinitely, seemingly as it had "failed silently". Shouldn't the `send` method raise an exception due to the invalid `int` type (since it only accepts `bytes` or `str`)?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `async` and `await` in Python, but I'm guessing `await asyncio.wait([consumer_task, producer_task])` will first wait for `consumer_task` to finish, before propagating any exception raised _asynchronously_ from `producer_task`.

Comment: If I'm looking at the right code [here](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/aa93c4ceca90a1798f86b2fc2b110a42f308d721/src/websockets/legacy/protocol.py#L672) then an exception _is_ raised when passing `data` of the wrong type.

Comment: Indeed, I put a `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION` as argument for the `asyncio.wait`, and at least now the code does not hang indefinitely. I'm trying to figure out now how to re-raise the exception from the future (though I guess it should be re-raised by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually lying in the `asyncio.wait` method, as hinted by Thomas' comments (thanks). Switching `asyncio.wait` for the [higher-level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44614131/13806326) `asyncio.gather` solved it.