# `asyncio.run()` does not wait for coroutine to finish

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm running this code in Python 3.7.3

```
import asyncio

async def fun(time):
    print(f"will wait for {time}")
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    print(f"done waiting for {time}")

async def async_cenas():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(fun(1))
    print("after 1")
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(fun(2))
    print("after 2")

def main():
    t1 = asyncio.run(async_cenas())
    print("ok main")
    print(t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("finished __name__")
```

And getting this output:

```
after 1
after 2
will wait for 1
will wait for 2
ok main
None
finished __name__
```

I was expecting to see also:

```
done waiting for 1
done waiting for 2
```

I.e., why was expecting `asyncio.run(X)` would wait for the coroutines to complete before proceeding.

Comment: What is your question? `run` waits for main coroutine, and than cancel all the other tasks, you could read the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/runners.py)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the source, that helped @NobbyNobbs

Comment: @larsks `run_until_complete` will have the exact same "problem" of waiting for only what you've told it to wait for. In fact, `asyncio.run` is a fairly straightforward wrapper around `loop.run_until_complete`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to wait for the completion of all tasks spawned by the `create_task`, then you need to do it explicitly by, for example, just `await` for them in turn or asyncio facilities like [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)  or [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives) (the difference is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231161/asyncio-gather-vs-asyncio-wait)). Otherwise, they will be canceled by the `asyncio.run` when exiting the main coroutine, which is passed to `asyncio.run`.

Example:

```
import asyncio

async def fun(time):
    print(f"will wait for {time}")
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    print(f"done waiting for {time}")

async def async_cenas():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(fun(1))
    print("after 1")
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(fun(2))
    print("after 2")
    await asyncio.wait({t1, t2}, return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)
    # or just
    # await t1
    # await t2

def main():
    t1 = asyncio.run(async_cenas())
    print("ok main")
    print(t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("finished __name__")
```

```
after 1
after 2
will wait for 1
will wait for 2
done waiting for 1
done waiting for 2
ok main
None
finished __name__
```

Comment: That was not clear to me from the documentation here https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#running-an-asyncio-program

Comment: Can I make it wait in the main() function? Or just in async_cenas()?

Comment: `await` works only inside `async def` functions (coroutines)

Comment: the documentation is not perfect but the source code, which is referenced in the comments, is pretty straightforward