# async Python: What is the difference between "await asyncio.gather(...)" and "asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(...)"?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I started reading about Async IO in Python, and I found different initialization of the event cycle in different sources in the examples.

One example uses:

```
await asyncio.gather(
    asyncio.create_task(task("One", work_queue)),
    asyncio.create_task(task("Two", work_queue)),
)
```

Another example uses:

```
ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [ioloop.create_task(foo()), ioloop.create_task(bar())]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
ioloop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
```

It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231161/asyncio-gather-vs-asyncio-wait) that `gather` is used mainly for high-level manipulation.

As I understood the key concepts in this question are: future objects and low/high-level async/await code.
Judging by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#id7), gather works with the list as a whole.
According to the function `asyncio.get_running_loop()` in the documentation, the information is incomprehensible to me.

But I still can't grasp the conceptual difference.
Or is it enough to remember that the first option is for simplified tasks, and the second one is for more precise settings?

Comment: [Python Asyncio: The Complete Guide](https://superfastpython.com/python-asyncio/) includes a discussion of the differences between the two. My take from a quick gloss is that the task API gives you more control over when the asynchronous code runs. Let us know if the guide is useful to you.

Comment: @TheLazyGraybeard Thanks a lot for the link, sorry I didn't answer right away, the material is pretty big. Everything is described in detail and clearly on this source, it's great.